# How can i integrate DocuSign with Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, docusignapi

we want to send documents from share point through DocuSign. Is there any simple solution for integration between DocuSign and Share Point?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  DocuSign has their own DocuSign for SharePoint product but it's all built on publicly available API.  https://www.docusign.com/solutions/microsoft